# Design a sequential processing of records

Tags: design, java, database, message-queue

About 10 to 15 records are processed per day with the time interval of 5 minutes between each record.

1. System A inserts a record in DB and sends id of that record to active mq.
2. System B Listener receives id from mq and pulls records from DB
3. System B processes that record and posts to System C using rest api call

If 1,2 & 3 records are posted one by one to mq from System A then sequence of records posted to System C should be same.

Due to outage, System C is down while posting record 2 but it came up while posting record 3. In this case, order is missed and record 2 is not posted at all.

I think below should be correct approach:

- Maintain status column in DB for each record
- If System B to C is successful update status as succcess
- Every time System B to C should check any unsuccessful records are there and process them from id lower to higher
- Scheduler which runs every 10 minutes can pull all the records which are not success and post to System C from id lower to higher

Please give your suggestion about this approach. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** This is existing system which is going to expire in 2 years so dont want robust changes.

Comment: negative voter pls provide comment always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When B is actively polling unsuccessful records from a database to send them to C again, it could also poll for the unprocessed records (maybe it is not even necessary to distinguish between unsuccessful and unprocessed records, except for gathering statistics). With a proper index on the status column, I guess this will unlikely become a bottleneck. So, every 10 minutes

- let B collect and process all unprocessed records
- send the records (sorted by ID) to C, but mark only the successfully sent records as "processed"
- at the next run of the scheduler, records which were not successfully received by C before will be sent again

In case order of processing really matters that much as you wrote, stop processing of B by the scheduler during one time slice as soon as the first transmission to C fails.

The point is, however: **this makes the message queue quite superfluous** - it is simply not needed here. When looking at numbers like "10 to 15 records a day", it is quite unclear why a database with polling isn't sufficient for this use case, especially when polling the unsuccessfully sent records is needed either.